# Spring JPA Repository Returning 500 After First Visit

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this Spring Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
public List<User> getUsersByUsername(@RequestParam username) {
    return userRepo.findByUsernameContaining(username);
}
```

And this JpaRepository method:

```
List<User> findByUsernameContaining(String username);
```

That has been working fine. But recently it started throwing an error if visited more than once. The 1st visit (after Spring Boot startup) returns the expected users successfully with a 200 status code. But all subsequent visits result in this error, which causes a 500 status code:

```
ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet 
[dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request 
processing failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
Parameter value [\] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [\] did 
not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [\] did 
not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]
```

(I recently upgraded from Spring Boot 2.0.4 to 2.6.6. Not sure if that could have triggered this?)

Nonetheless, if I change that repository method to add @Param the endpoint works. It no longer errors on 2nd and later visits when written this way:

```
List<User> findByUsernameContaining(@Param("username") String username);
```

Seems strange, as my other repository methods don't explicitly use `@Param`. Why would adding `@Param` fix this? Isn't explicitly using `@Param` unnecessary? And either way, why would the endpoint always work the first time it's hit, then on later hits throw that error? And what does the error even mean? There's no `\` parameter value being used that I know of.

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2476

Comment: Turns out upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6.8 fixed this issue for me. Thanks, @Nahuel Giani!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2476) in Spring Boot versions 2.6.3 through 2.6.6.

Upgrading to Spring Boot 2.6.8 resolved it for me.